# org Images in LaTeX export set default width

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

By default these org lines:

```
my image:
[[./figure1.png]]
```

are exported into these ones in latex:

```
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./figure1.png}
```

How can I change the default value of width `\width=.9\linewidth`?

I know that it is possible to change locally just before each picture, but it is possible to set another default value?

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.98\linewidth
[[./figure1.png]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize this via the variable `org-latex-image-default-width`.

To set just for the current file, you could put the following at the top of the file:

```
#+BIND: org-latex-image-default-width "0.98\\linewidth"
```

Comment: Good answer, just note that `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` needs to be non-nil for this to work.  I also found that quotes and escaping the backslash was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

To put in .emacs (emacs config file) :

```
(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)
```

To put in org file header :

```
#+BIND: org-latex-image-default-width ".98\\linewidth"
```